# Initialize var to empty

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a LINQ query that starts with var LinqQuery. But I want to put the LinqQuery in an if statement so it process is certain attributes are null or not. I need to set the var LinqQuery outside the if statement because I have code that loops through the LinqQuery. Is it initialize the var LinqQuery outside the if statement. Something like var LinqQuery = string.Empty?

```
var lQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("account")
    where (a["name"].Equals(lLead.AccountName) &&
        a["address1_postalcode"].Equals(lLead.ZipCode) &&
        a["address1_stateorprovince"].Equals(lLead.State)) ||
        (a["address1_line1"].Equals(lLead.Address1) &&
        a["address1_postalcode"].Equals(lLead.ZipCode) &&
        a["address1_city"].Equals(lLead.City))
    select new
    {
        Name = !a.Contains("name") ? string.Empty : a["name"],
        City = !a.Contains("address1_city") ? string.Empty : a["address1_city"],
        State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"],
        Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"],
        AccountId = !a.Contains("accountid") ? string.Empty : a["accountid"]
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `var` keyword just allows the compiler to infer the type, so in your example `var linqQuery = string.Empty`, the type of `linqQuery` would be string. Post some code and we be able to provide more information.

Comment: This will be much easier to understand with a small piece of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to initialize it to a type compatible with the final shape of the query, or just explicitly type it.

```
IQueryable<Foo> theQuery; // explicitly type it 
// var theQuery = db.Foos.AsQueryable(); // alternately infer it 

if (blah)
   theQuery = db.Foos.Where(...);
else 
   theQuery = db.Foos.OrderBy(...);

theQuery = theQuery.Where(...); // keep chaining 
//etc;
```

Note that the type infers *once*, you cannot initially set it to `string.Empty` and then later expect to be able to use it with a Linq-to-Sql query. That would not work, just like using explicit typing in such a scenario would not work. You would not expect to be able to do this:

```
string blah = "";
blah = db.Foos.Where(f => f.Bar > 20);
```

Nor could you replace `string` with `var` and expect to succeed. `var` does not mean `dynamic`.

Comment: `var does not mean dynamic` -- exactly.

Comment: Sorry to sound dense but where you initialize `theQuery` with `IQueryable<Foo>  theQuery;`, what does the `Foo` represent? Thanks

Comment: @Gareth, in this case, it is a fictional class name, and you would use a real class name in its place in working code. Foo and Bar are commonly used as fictional stand-ins for real types when providing sample code where the actual class isn't important.

Comment: Thanks, Understand that FFoo would be a placeholder, just didn't understand that it was to represent a class. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in a loop but might not set it's value try initializing it to `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`